# PHP/MySQL User Login Form not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a ton of trouble trying to make a user log-in form for my website... I want it to set a cookie when the user logs in, so that on other forms that they use, their information will automatically be filled in. Here's the code I have so far

```
<?php 
if ((!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
    header("Location: userlogin.html");
    exit;
}


 //connect to server and select database
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database1")
                or die(mysqli_error());
// use mysqli_real_escape_string to clean the input
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);

//create and issue the query 
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM frmak_form_1 WHERE 
    username = '".$username."' AND 
    password = PASSWORD('".$password."');";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

// get the number of rows in the result set; should be 1 if a match
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
     while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $username = stripslashes($info['username']);
        }

   // set authorization cookie
          setcookie("auth", "1", 0, "/", "mydomain.com", 0);

 //create display string
    $display_block = "
            <p>Welcome, ".$username."!</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=\"submitReview.php\">Click here to submit a Review!</a></li>
            </ul>";
            } else {
                //redirect back to the login form if not authorized
                header("Location: userlogin.html");
                exit;
            } 

// close connection to MySQL
            mysqli_close($mysqli);
    ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>User Login REDIRECT!!!!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $display_block; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone PLEASE tell me what is wrong with my code? When I enter what I KNOW is CORRECT user name and password into the fields, and hit SUBMIT, it redirects back to the same page... which is what it is supposed to do if I didn't enter the right info. What's going on, here???

Comment: You are missing a close double quote after $password."') before the ;

Comment: Use prepared statements. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` doesn't protect against all types of SQL-injection.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? This code has a syntax error so it shouldn't run at all.

Answer (score -1):

If it is redirecting back to the login page you may have the CGI parameter names wrong. This debug code should show you the user name and password - if it doesn't then your problem is in the login form. It could be the names don't match `<input name='user'>` when it should be `<input name='username'>` another possibility is that you used get in place of post. You should have `<form action='next.php' method='post'>`

```
<?php 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);
echo "DEBUG: $username $password";
die("Just checking");
if ((!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
    header("Location: userlogin.html");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: password = PASSWORD('".$password."');";

SQL semicolon termination is also needed.

Comment: This is probably a copying error, otherwise his script wouldn't run at all because of the syntax error. Since he's getting redirected, it must be parsing.

Comment: I fixed the quote at the end, still not working. I also then put the semicolon in... still didn't work...

Comment: Please edit the question to show us. If you fix the indentation and remove redundant blank lines that would be a huge help. It sound pedantic but these things really do help understand the problem.

Comment: I edited the question... removed a bunch of the blank lines. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks, tried the DEBUG code... shows username and password... still doesn't work...

Comment: Fixed it. Realized I was using the wrong database name the whole time!!!! D'oh...